# Different run-time checking of printf() for %s?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, printf

I know that, to use [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) correctly, we need to further pass in same number of values according to what are defined in the `const char* format`, i.e. `%s/%f/%d...`.

```
int printf( const char* format, ... );
```

I just noticed that, although not recommended, it will run without any run-time errors if we don't pass in any values, like the following (of course, we will get un-expected results):

```
printf("%a"); // ok
printf("%c"); // ok
printf("%d"); // ok
printf("%e"); // ok
printf("%f"); // ok
printf("%g"); // ok
printf("%i"); // ok
printf("%o"); // ok
printf("%p"); // ok
printf("%u"); // ok
printf("%x"); // ok
```

If this will holds for all formats, I will feel no surprised by thinking that `printf()` doesn't do any run-time checking. Weird thing is that, it will give run-time error for `%s` (also seems the only one).

```
printf("%s"); // run-time error: Access violation reading location
```

Even more interesting thing is that, it seems that it only run-time checks for the first or consecutive of `%s`. Check out the following examples:

```
printf("%s%s", "xxx"); // run-time error: Access violation reading location
printf("%s%d%s", "xxx"); // ok
```

So, my question is that:

- Does `printf()` run-time check differently for `%s` compared with other formats? And why?
- Why does `printf()` only run-time check for the first or consecutive of `%s`?

ps: I tested it under VS2010, OS: Win7x64.

Comment: This is really a *C* question, there is nothing *C++* specific in the question.

Comment: Read on [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). `printf` is one such function. With variadic functions, you _can't_ have any runtime check on the arguments, so you must rely on another known argument, such as the format string in case of `printf`. If you as the programmer fail to give it the correct argument, it will read whatever garbage there is on the stack instead. `%d` and others print those garbage values. `%s` takes that garbage value as pointer and dereferences it, which causes a segmentation fault (access violation).

Comment: I am also curious, doesn't printf_s offer any check here?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour:  Just because there isn't any code here which *won't* compile under C doesn't make this a question about C.  That it is ill-advised to use `sprintf` under C++ is irrelevant.  The only thing that's relevant is how the OP is compiling the code.  If it's being compiled as C++, then the question should be tagged C++.

Comment: @JohnDibling also the C++ standard falls back on C99 for `printf` as well, so it should not really change the answer to the main question. It can see how it can debated though, you can roll it back if you wish or add the *C++* tag, I won't get into a rollback war, if I feel strongly enough I will just flag and let a mod figure it out.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour:  Consider:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker

Comment: @JohnDibling hmmm, that does not really follow the practice that I see everyday but perhaps a lot of people are doing it wrong.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour:  In this particular case, the answers for C and C++ would be the same.  That may not always be the case however.  I re-set the tag.  Flag if you want a moderator to intervene.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour:  Right, it is very common for [C++] tags to be changed to [C] tags without consulting the OP.  I think it's (potentially) incorrect to do so from a technical level, rude to the OP, and presumptious.  It's become a pet peeve of mine of late.  I don't blame *you* -- you're just doing what everybody does.

Comment: @JohnDibling if you have a lot of examples maybe this should be revisited on meta again. I see the point but just b/c someone is using a *C++* compiler does not make it a *C++* question but I am willing to change my mind.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour:  If I were to open a new question about this on meta, it would get closed as a dupe and downvoted in to oblivion.  (I get d/v a lot on meta. :) )  I'd like to hear your viewpoint.  Are you willing add a new answer to the link above?

Comment: @JohnDibling I have to think about this some more.

Comment: Indeed, if the OP is compiling as C++, then this is a C++ question. But, OP, you really should either switch to C or write proper C++! When you've switched to a C compiler let us know so we can re-tag and get you some C expertise in here.

Comment: @JohnDibling Lightness posted a new answer which I agree with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the *C++* standard fall back on the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) which says this is undefined behavior in section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which covers `printf` with respect format specifiers, says:

> [...]If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So as the standard says in the definition for undefined behavior:

> Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable
>   results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

anything can happen.

Since `printf` is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) it has to rely on the caller to correctly represent the data passed in. So run time checking is not possible. Although several compilers do provide compile time checking, for example `gcc` even provides this checking as an attribute [format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) which can be used with your own functions.

Answer (score 2):

[ED: Note this question was originally tagged C++, and this answer assumes OP is compiling as C++]

> although not recommended, it will run without any run-time errors if
> we don't pass in any values,

No, this yields Undefined Behavior.  Anything can happen, including *what you expect*.  Doesn't mean it's OK.

`printf` does *no* runtime checking of whatever junk you send it, if you send it anything at all.  The onus is upon **you** to ensure you write correct code.

By the way ion your later case where you were getting "unhandled exception" errors -- this was not the result of `sprintf` doing runtime checking.  This was another manifestation of Undefined Behavior.

All of this odd and dangerous behavior is a result of the fact that sprintf is a type-unsafe, dangerous function.  It is very easy to write code that the compiler will happily accept, and will seem to run fine in testing or even in production for a while, but exhibits Undefined Behavior in some subtle way.  This usually bites you on Fridays an hour before you're going out for the weekend.

The life lesson here is:  **don't use sprintf in C++**.  Use something modern and type-safe instead, like streams.

Answer (score 2):

There are no runtime checks.  `printf` will just blindly read whatever gibberish is on the stack (or whatever var-arg mechanism is being used).  In the case of `%s`, it interprets the gibberish as a pointer, and then attempts to read stuff from that address, typically leading to an access violation.<sup>*</sup>

In essence, what you're seeing is *undefined behaviour*.

---

<sub>* Ok, I guess this is a sort-of runtime check, at the OS/HW level.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are no runtime checks, techically hard to do those. But there are compilation checks available.

With GCC it's `-Wall`.
With Visual Studio you need to run it's static analysis tool (available on the more expensive versions).

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behaviour, so anything may happen. In practice the difference you see may be due to the fact that all other specifiers you used refer to values directly on the stack, so garbage is displayed, but it does not crash. With %s it is different - the random value is treated as pointer, and your program accesses the random area of memory, so most likely it crashes.
Having said that, it is still undefined and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%d")`: An attempt to read 4 bytes from a possibly-illegal memory address.

`printf("%s")`: An attempt to read an unknown number of bytes from a possibly-illegal memory address, until a byte with value 0 is encountered.

In both cases, it's a "matter of luck" whether or not a memory access violation will take place.

But as you can understand, these chances are much higher in the case of `"%s"`.